# How to use http-equiv and name attribute at the same time?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, http-equiv

I was researching about meta tags in HTML and I ended up on a [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e) that suggested that **I don't set the name and htt-equiv attribute at the same time.** I read [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e) that if I need to support IE8 OR IE9 then it's recommended to use the http-equiv attribute with X-UA Compatible value. My website needs to be supported by older versions of IE so i use the following line of code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

But at the same time, i also want to provide extra information such as description of my webpage and also specify keywords. Those are set by using the name attributes. Like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
```

But according to several webpages, I cannot use the http-equiv and name attributes at the same time. **So how do I ensure compatibility with older versions of IE and extra information about the webpage at the same time?**

I'm quite confused, please enlighten me.

Comment: Um... not sure where you're getting your advice from, but it's perfectly normal to put all those meta tags into the same page. Using one does not exclude you from using another. You probably shouldn't put `http-equiv` and `name` together in the *same* meta tag, but having multiple meta tags is not a problem.

Comment: On the off-chance this advice is true, you might consider using the HTTP header form of `X-UA-Compatible`.

Comment: @Simba, I think you are right to suggest that maybe they meant to say that they should not be set in the same meta tag. That is not the only explanation that makes sense regarding that statement.